# Equivalent condition for continuity of a map between metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Recall that for a map $f:X\to Y$ between metric spaces, $f$ is continuous if and only if for every sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x\in X$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)\in Y$. Can we replace the latter condition to the following weaker condition? For every sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x\in X$, there is a subsequence of the sequence $f(x_n)$ converging to $f(x)\in Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since every subsequence of $f(x_n)$ then has the same property. I explained this concept in the lemma that is contained in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049790/how-do-i-show-that-the-map-u-to-int-u2-is-weakly-continuous/4051219#4051219) answer. You just apply it to $f(x_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f$ satisfies the condition, but it is not continuous at a certain point $x$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$ such that the sequence $(f(x_n))$ doesn't converge to $f(x)$.

What does this mean? There is $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for every $n$, we can find $m>n$ with $d(f(x_m),f(x))\ge\varepsilon$.

This can be used to make a subsequence $(x'_n)$ of the sequence $(x_n)$ so that $f(x'_n)$ has always distance $\ge\varepsilon$ from $f(x)$. Start by choosing $x'_1=x_{m_1}$, where $m_1$ is the first index $m_1$ for which $f(x_m)\ge\varepsilon$; then define recursively $m_{k+1}$ to be the first index greater than $m_k$ such that $f(x_{m_{k+1}})\ge\varepsilon$.

This is a contradiction, because no subsequence of $f(x'_n)$ can converge to $f(x)$.